# resultSet returning false when it should return true

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to retrieve data from Oracle database in Eclipse using JDBC. Even though the table has entries present in it and the the SQL query runs is Oracle[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CygCx.png), result Set returns false and never enters the loop.
Below is the code snippet:

```
public List<InvoiceModel> getProcDets() throws SQLException {   
    List<InvoiceModel> procDets = new ArrayList<InvoiceModel>();

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM PROC_DETAILS";
    connect();

    PreparedStatement statement = jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

    while(resultSet.next()) {
        String adid=resultSet.getString("ADID");
        String fName=resultSet.getString("FULL_NAME");
        String email=resultSet.getString("EMAIL");

        InvoiceModel Invoice = new InvoiceModel(fName, adid, email);
        procDets.add(Invoice);
    }

    resultSet.close();
    statement.close();
    disconnect();
    return procDets;   
}
```

Any help/suggestion/improvement is appreciated!

Comment: If you're sure that the query is OK, then the problem is elsewhere. Are you connecting to the correct environment as the correct user? Did you not insert this data in a different db connection? If yes, did you commit in that client's session?

Comment: This snippet happens to be a part of the DAO file where only a single connection is being made to correct DB. This is the only method where resultSet returns a false. The session has been committed also

Comment: The session needed to be committed!! Thanks for the help!!!